# CentOS 6.4 PHP MCrypt

Tags: centos, yum, repository, php-mcrypt

I am trying to install the `php-mcrypt` extension for my CentOs 6.4 server but it is falling over with this message:

```
[root@vps /]# yum install php-mcrypt
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirrors.vooservers.com
 * epel: mirror01.th.ifl.net
 * epel-debuginfo: mirror01.th.ifl.net
 * epel-source: mirror01.th.ifl.net
 * extras: mirrors.vooservers.com
 * updates: mirrors.vooservers.com
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-mcrypt.i386 0:5.1.6-5.el5 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-api = 20041225 for package: php-mcrypt-5.1.6-5.el5.i386
--> Processing Dependency: libmcrypt.so.4 for package: php-mcrypt-5.1.6-5.el5.i386
--> Running transaction check
---> Package libmcrypt.i386 0:2.5.7-5.el5 will be installed
---> Package php-mcrypt.i386 0:5.1.6-5.el5 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-api = 20041225 for package: php-mcrypt-5.1.6-5.el5.i386
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: php-mcrypt-5.1.6-5.el5.i386 (epel)
           Requires: php-api = 20041225
           Installed: php-common-5.3.3-22.el6.i686 (@base)
               php-api = 20090626
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

I have (to my knowledge) installed the repos correctly here is my epel.repo file:

```
[epel]
name=Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - $basearch
#baseurl=http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/$basearch
mirrorlist=https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=epel-6&arch=$basearch
failovermethod=priority
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-6
```

And my repolist:

```
repo id          repo name                                                status
base             CentOS-6 - Base                                          4,802
epel             Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - i386             5,931
epel-debuginfo   Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - i386 - Debug     1,816
epel-source      Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - i386 - Source        0
extras           CentOS-6 - Extras                                           12
updates          CentOS-6 - Updates                                         481
repolist: 13,042
```

I even have remi installed but I can't seem to be able to get the php-mcrypt extension installed for ZF2. For some reason it seems to be pulling from the `el5` repo even though all my repos are `el6`?

Anyone know what's going on?

Thanks

Nathan

Comment: Have you already tried to clean your yum cache?
`yum clean all`

Comment: ok, did that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clean your yum cache first using

`yum clean all`